How can a man get rid of his sexual and romantic desires ? Does practising Kundalini help?
How can a man get rid of his sexual and romantic attraction towards women ?
As one can't get Moksha without getting rid of all forms of desire and sexual desires are strongest form of desire.
Even BrahmaRishis like Vishwamitra, Parashara got diverted because of it.
Veda Vyasa son Suka totally got rid of sexual desires and he got Moksha.
Does practising Kundalini get one rid of sexual and romantic desires ?
Any other way to get rid of it ?

This question is similar to: What destroys Kaam in a man?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Similar2

@PrasannaR Kundalini

The lower illusory happiness of lust can only be given up from the root by experiencing the higher taste of spiritual life as described in the Bhagavad Gita 2.59. It can be through any of the authorized practices including Kundalini awakening.

visaya vinivartante niraharasya dehinah rasa-varjam raso 'py asya
param drstva nivartate
The embodied soul may be restricted from sense enjoyment, though the
taste for sense objects remains. But, ceasing such engagements by
experiencing a higher taste, he is fixed in consciousness.

To the extent one experiences bliss of the self or service to the supersoul, to that degree lust would be reduced and ultimately burnt to ashes. At that stage, the Sadhaka becomes Jivana-Mukta and is never born again in the material world.

@Hairhara this river is asking the same question in different tone..no need to answer this question or i dont know whether river tries to increase points by question same with different wording.. im voting close
